# C#: Get variable value from a variable

Tags: c#

I have been trying to access the variable value that internally itself is a variable and I am not even sure if it possible.

```
string var1 = "var2";
string var2 = "testvar";
```

So, here, is there any possibility to access value "testvar" using var1 variable?

Thanks!

> To explain better the scenario better, here is the actual code -
>   Reading the variables from the excel column
>   and the value of those variables are present in the code

```
//Excel codeFieldsListLocal column in CodeFields.xlsx
//row 1: var1
//row 2: var2
//row 3: var3
//row 4: var4


using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using HL7Spy.Core;
using HL7Spy.Core.Hl7;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public partial class DynamicClassTest : HL7Spy.Core.BaseCustomFunction
{
    string _outFileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),"out.txt"); 
    string _inFileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),"CodeFields.xlsx"); 
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

    string var1 = "John";
    string var2 = "Tom";
    string var3 = "Bruce";
    string var4 = "Hugh";
    string var5 = "Peter";
    string var6 = "Steve";
    string var7 = "Bob";


    StreamWriter _file;
    /Called for a set of data
    public override void Run()
    {
        List<string> codeFieldsListLocal = new List<string>();
        // create the file to be written out
        _file = new StreamWriter(_outFileName, false);
        codeFieldsListLocal = getCodeFieldsNamesFromExcel();

        for(int i = 0; i < codeFieldsListLocal.Count; i++) {
            _file.WriteLine(codeFieldsListLocal[i]); /* --> Here I wanted to display the values instead of the variable names, is it possbile? Like John, Tom and others; and not var1, var2...*/

        }
    }
    //Called at time of code closure
    public override void OnFinish() {
        _file.WriteLine("OnFinish");
        _file.Close();
        // launch notepad to display the file.
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Notepad",_outFileName);
    }
    //Creating a list of variables from the excel column
    public List<string> getCodeFieldsNamesFromExcel () {
        List<string> codeFieldsListLocal = new List<string>();
        Excel.Workbook workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(_inFileName,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)sheet.UsedRange.Columns[3];
        object[,] currentColumn = (object[,])range.Cells.Value2;
        for (int i = 2; i < currentColumn.Length; i++) {
            codeFieldsListLocal.Add(currentColumn[i,1].ToString());
            _file.WriteLine(currentColumn[i,1]);
        }
        return codeFieldsListLocal;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not make any sense.  Can you edit and try to describe your issue more clearly?

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377). Instead of telling us what you're doing you need to tell us what your goal is, because what you are doing makes no sense at all.

Comment: It is not possible to do what you're asking for local variables. It is possible on class-member variables (fields)-- see linked duplicate question.

Comment: @JohnWu I am not sure if its a duplicate or not yet.  OPs code example seems to suggest that they want something different than that

Comment: @maccettura Without more context we do not know whether these are local variables or members.

Comment: That's not a thing you would normally do in C#. Can you say why you want to do this? If you want to make a lookup table that looks up values from strings, use a dictionary.

Comment: Thankyou for the responses.
Here is the realistic scenario that I am having -
1. I am reading an excel column which are actually variables and currently, those are being read as list in the code.
2. And, I have data which correspond to the value of those variables.
3. When I try to loop and display value of each list item, I get variable names instead of the data values that I have.

Comment: There is no API to translate a string containing the name of a *local* variable into the value of the variable, you're going to have to write a switch or similar with the known variables. As provided in the duplicate, reflection can translate member names to the member/member values, but local variables and method parameters are not covered by this.